# How to install other app within a app like Bloom did on iOS platform?

Tags: ios, app-store

How to install other apps with in a app on iOS platform?

For example, in the app "Bloom", pull up to the bottom, and click "PEAK", a view of "Peek" store detail will show, and you can download the app "PEAK" in this view. You did not need to open the app store, all happened in the "Bloom" app. Anyone has ideas of how to implement such function?

The bloom app:
https://itunes.apple.com/app/id1174015502

Comment: If you want to download directly without peaking, then you can OpenURL: `itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=OtherAppstoreInfoPlistURL.plist` which will prompt the user to install that app..

Answer (score 2):

The view is [SKStoreProductViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skstoreproductviewcontroller)